# Can a plugin differentiate syndication feeds from actual site views?

Tags: plugin-development, rss, api

Is there anything in the WordPress API that I can use in a plugin to detect whether the current request to WordPress is a pull of the syndication feed -- as opposed to an actual view of the web-site?

I ask this because it is critical that one specific behavior of the plugin be different for syndication feeds than for actual web-site views.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_feed ?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic -- Thank you very much! You are a lifesaver! I don't know why Google didn't give me this information -- but for some reason it didn't (and believe me, I searched and searched). I'm glad you were able to provide me with this information. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @TheDeadMedic -- Oh --- I tried your suggestion --- and it works beautifully. :-) Thanks. :-)

Comment: I'll post it as an answer and we can mark this question resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the template tag [`is_feed()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_feed) to determine if the current request is for a feed:

```
if ( is_feed() ) {
    // It's a feed!
} else {
    // Regular 'ol WordPress
}
```

Note you'll need to use the function *after* the request has been parsed (i.e. on or after the `parse_query` hook).